# having problem with installing genymotion in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion

When I want to install genymotion in android studio, I should go to plugins and click on browse repositories. But i can`t see the "browse repositories" button. Is my android studio in different version? What should I do?

[image: screen shot of android studio window]

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 3.5

Settings--> Plugins

Then click on market place box and search for Genymotion [image]

Answer (score -1):

Android studio has built in emulators, you should just use that. You can download it from android studio itself. So there’s no need for a third party emulator.

Check out this link:

https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator/